# Cannot connect passively to any ftp server; timeout when retrieving directory listing

Tags: windows, networking, ftp

My laptop has not been able to connect passively to any ftp service. When connecting through FileZilla I can see that it connects and logs in just fine but will always timeout when retrieving the directory listing. For example, when attempting to connect to ftp://ftp.ncbi.nih.gov/ passively, this is the FileZilla output:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.ncbi.nih.gov
Status: Connecting to 130.14.250.12:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is the current directory
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (130,14,250,12,195,109).
Command:    MLSD
Error:  Connection timed out after 20 seconds of inactivity
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

However, when using FileZilla's site manager to connect actively I can retrieve the directory listing:

```
Status: Resolving address of ftp.ncbi.nih.gov
Status: Connecting to 130.14.250.11:21...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
Status: Logged in
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Status: Directory listing of "/" successful
```

---

Here is a list of what I have tried so far:

- The router is a `CenturyLink Zyxel PK5001z`. The firmware has been up to date for a while now `CZP003-4.3.009.31`. Restarting appears to temporarily fix the issue but will come back in an undetermined amount of time (day or two).
- The issue is only affecting my computer. Every other device connected to the router appears to handle multiple passive ftp connections.
- The wireless card on the laptop is a `Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 2230`. I have tried updating the drivers, disconnecting and reconnecting from the router, disabling and renabling in device manager; all have had no effect.
- I have checked and the setting to `Make this PC Discoverable` is and has been set on for this network.
- Connecting to the router via ethernet allows passive ftp to work normally but this isn't an option.
- When plugging an older `Netgear WNDR3700` into the Zyxel and connecting to it, this also appears to fix it but I'm not sure about having two routers active at the same time is a good idea.
- I have tried setting the computer as the DMZ and disabling Windows Defender and Windows Firewall at the same time; this also had no effect.

Comment: To troubleshoot, you need to do more than just look for obvious errors, disable **all** security including MalwareBytes, Windows Defender, and Windows Firewall one by one to see if it works and which one is blocking.  If the issue persists, try it from safe mode with networking.

Comment: Matthew, disable the Windows FW and then try connecting to the FTP site in PASV mode and report back your results.The passive port per `130,14,250,12,195,109` is `50029` from what I calculate per the formula.

Comment: I've just disabled Windows FW, turned off Windows Defender Real-time protection, and malwarebytes is never on unless I start it since it is the free version. It hasn't changed a thing. I restarted my computer just to be sure it was all disabled and tried again but still the same results.

Comment: I thought the issue was my adapter because the problem went away by using ethernet but when using one of our older routers and connecting to it the problem went away too. The issue appears to be coming from the `Zyxel PK5001z`.

Comment: @Matthew Please see this here: https://www.photosync-app.com/photosync/en/help/connectivity/answers/how-to-change-the-windows-10-network-type-from-public-to-private.html and then ensure that the wifi NIC has this setting set to ON and see if that resolves the problem? Please tag me back with the `@` symbol followed by my name to let me know your results. There are other ways to change this with group policy as well but if this is the problem, I will gladly add an answer for you.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I checked and the setting was already on `Make this PC discoverable`. I will note however for some unknown reason the zyxel router has decided to function normally with passive ftp since yesterday.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT Not surprisingly the issue returned again. I decided to restart the router and it fixed itself (unplugged it last time to try the older router is probably why it fixed itself last time). No idea why it only seems to be acting weird with only my computer though. I don't want to restart the router every time it comes back.

Comment: Look into updating the router's firmware in case there's a bug, etc. at this level. Otherwise, perhaps setup a rule in the router to say, "anything to or from 130.14.250.10, allow it through for all ports".  Not sure how you'd configure the router via it's configuration interface with such rule but something to consider if you trust that IP address and it's important enough to your in what sounds like a home network setup or perhaps a small business network.

Comment: @PIMP_JUICE_IT I have had to wait for the issue to come back again. I've setup my laptop as the DMZ on the network since the last router reboot but it hasn't changed anything. The firmware has been up to date and the same now for months `CZP003-4.3.009.31`.

Answer (score 0):

it seems like there is something blocking your wireless connection to the FTP server. Do you have any other laptop to try. Check your firewall/router settings and make sure that the ports required for the FTP are not blocked.

Comment: I've tried all of that and narrowed the issue down to my wireless card timing out with passive ftp. Connecting to the router via ethernet seems to fix it; it isn't the firewall or windows. Every other laptop/phone connects just fine. I don't know if this is fixable or if I will have to get some usb wifi adapter.